# MYSQL error : #3699 - Timeout exceeded in regular expression match

Tags: mysql, regex, timeout, full-text-search

Running a MYSQL query with REGEX and I get a timeout error.

I have a Bitnami NGINX Wordpress stack on AWS with Ubuntu 16.

Using MYSQL 8.0.16

What settings in MYSQL (or whereever else) do I need to change to stop this error?

help appreciated..

tried playing with the my.cnf file and restarting MYSQL but I dont know which timeout setting, there seems to be several

this is the SQL query

```sql
REPLACE INTO wp_term_relationships (term_taxonomy_id, object_id) SELECT '272',  ID
FROM  `wp_posts` 
   WHERE (
   post_title REGEXP 'German|Deutsch|Berlin|Hamburg|Munich|München|Cologne|Köln|Frankfurt|Stuttgart|Düsseldorf|Dortmund|Essen|Leipzig|Bremen|Dresden|Hanover|Hannover|Nuremberg|Nürnberg|Duisburg|Bochum|Wuppertal|Bielefeld|Bonn|Münster|Karlsruhe|Mannheim|Augsburg|Wiesbaden|Gelsenkirchen|Mönchengladbach|Braunschweig|Chemnitz|Kiel|Aachen|Halle|Saale|Magdeburg|Freiburg|Krefeld|Lübeck|Oberhausen|Erfurt|Mainz|Rostock|Kassel|Hagen|Hamm|Saarbrücken|Mülheim|Potsdam|Ludwigshafen|Oldenburg|Leverkusen|Osnabrück|Solingen|Heidelberg|Herne|Neuss|Darmstadt|Paderborn|Regensburg|Ingolstadt|Würzburg|Fürth|Wolfsburg|Offenbach|Ulm|Heilbronn|Pforzheim|Göttingen|Bottrop|Trier|Recklinghausen|Reutlingen|Bremerhaven|Koblenz|Bergisch Gladbach|Jena|Remscheid|Erlangen|Moers|Siegen|Hildesheim|Salzgitter|Baden-Württemberg|Bavaria|Bayern|Berlin|Brandenburg|Bremen|Hesse|Hessen|Lower Saxony|Niedersachsen|Mecklenburg-Vorpommern|North Rhine-|Westphalia|Nordrhein-Westfalen|Rhineland-Palatinate|Rheinland-Pfalz|Saarland|Saxony|Sachsen|Saxony-Anhalt|Sachsen-Anhalt|Schleswig-Holstein|Thuringia|Thüringen' 
   OR post_content REGEXP 'German|Deutsch|Berlin|Hamburg|Munich|München|Cologne|Köln|Frankfurt|Stuttgart|Düsseldorf|Dortmund|Essen|Leipzig|Bremen|Dresden|Hanover|Hannover|Nuremberg|Nürnberg|Duisburg|Bochum|Wuppertal|Bielefeld|Bonn|Münster|Karlsruhe|Mannheim|Augsburg|Wiesbaden|Gelsenkirchen|Mönchengladbach|Braunschweig|Chemnitz|Kiel|Aachen|Halle|Saale|Magdeburg|Freiburg|Krefeld|Lübeck|Oberhausen|Erfurt|Mainz|Rostock|Kassel|Hagen|Hamm|Saarbrücken|Mülheim|Potsdam|Ludwigshafen|Oldenburg|Leverkusen|Osnabrück|Solingen|Heidelberg|Herne|Neuss|Darmstadt|Paderborn|Regensburg|Ingolstadt|Würzburg|Fürth|Wolfsburg|Offenbach|Ulm|Heilbronn|Pforzheim|Göttingen|Bottrop|Trier|Recklinghausen|Reutlingen|Bremerhaven|Koblenz|Bergisch Gladbach|Jena|Remscheid|Erlangen|Moers|Siegen|Hildesheim|Salzgitter|Baden-Württemberg|Bavaria|Bayern|Berlin|Brandenburg|Bremen|Hesse|Hessen|Lower Saxony|Niedersachsen|Mecklenburg-Vorpommern|North Rhine-|Westphalia|Nordrhein-Westfalen|Rhineland-Palatinate|Rheinland-Pfalz|Saarland|Saxony|Sachsen|Saxony-Anhalt|Sachsen-Anhalt|Schleswig-Holstein|Thuringia|Thüringen'
   )
   AND post_type = 'post'
```

> #3699 - Timeout exceeded in regular expression match.

*update - not sure how to add an image to comments, so will add here.

variable settings, cheers @Rick James on how list them

[image]

Comment: i would suggest using `FULLTEXT` indexes and using full text search with `MATCH(...) AGAINST(...)` instead ..

Comment: Regular expression matching can't be indexed, so this will require very expensive full-table scans.

Comment: *"Regular expression matching can't be indexed, so this will require very expensive full-table scans"* @Barmar You mean in general or MySQL only as iam pretty sure PostgreSQL supports indexing for regular expression matching..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I meant MySQL. It won't even use an index for something like `REGEXP '^foo.*'`, even though this is equivalent to `LIKE 'foo%'`, which will use an index.

Comment: *"I meant MySQL."* @Barmar well Oracle Corp has added lots or features/performance/better optimizer to MySQL 8 so who knows maybe indexing for regular expression matching is on the list..

Comment: *"It won't even use an index for something like REGEXP '^foo.*', even though this is equivalent to LIKE 'foo%', which will use an index"*  True @Barmar the MySQL optimizer now does not even see if a REGEX is really needed or that can be possibly replaced with a LIKE which might can use a index. .

Comment: @RaymondNijland I read through the list of 8.0 changes a week or two ago, I don't recall anything like that. I just tried it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wg5Khg8kuTMSzw35wXc7LP/0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SET GLOBAL regexp_time_limit=1024;
```

(see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_regexp_time_limit) for the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

"Timeout" is presumably due to a slow query against a large table.  So, let's address the speed of the query.

- `REPLACE` is `DELETE` + `INSERT`.
- `REPLACE is slow due to the`DELETE`.  And it will lose`term_order` if you have already set it.
- Consider using `INSERT IGNORE` instead.
- The `WHERE` clause, due to the `OR` and the `REGEXP`, will need to scan the entire table.  A `FULLTEXT` index could avoid that; see below.
- Refactoring the `REGEXP` won't help much; changing to `LIKE` is likely to be slower; etc.
- If the timeout is truely inside the `REGEXP` engine, then you may need to run the query a few cities at a time.

`FULLTEXT` would greatly improve the speed.  But, if you don't want to go that direction, the next best is changing `REPLACE` to `INSERT IGNORE`.

The `FULLTEXT` approach is:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD FULLTEXT(post_title, post_content);  -- one-time task

INSERT IGNORE INTO ... (...)
    SELECT 272, ID
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE MATCH(post_title, post_content)
              AGAINST('German Deutsch Berlin Hamburg Munich München ...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

(There may be an issue with handling of accents, depending on the version of MySQL and which `ENGINE` is used.)

Comment: HI thanks, is it possible to do your statement above and still use regex?  I managed to get the regex working by using the answer above (by reformatting the regex with a trie). 

I also found an online tool to make a trie.

http://kemio.com.ar/tools/lst-trie-re.php

however my code is still clumsy because I am repeating the regex, once for post_title and once for post_content, your code is clean and neat.

How can I use INSERT IGNORE INTO and WHERE MATCH(post_title, post_content) like you did but with REGEX?

sorry I am just a script kiddy. help appreciated :)

Comment: also.. I am still wondering though - why don't I get a timeout on my local stack (with my old code)? I only get a timeout on my AWS version. 
What is the mysql setting to increase timeout limit?

Comment: @BenedictHarris - `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';`  -- do on both servers, then compare.  Are they both 8.0.16?

Comment: thanks Rick, that isolated the difference. Turns out my local stack just misses these settings

mysqlx_connect_timeout   30
mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout   60
mysqlx_interactive_timeout   28800
mysqlx_port_open_timeout   0
mysqlx_read_timeout   30
mysqlx_wait_timeout   28800
mysqlx_write_timeout   60

Comment: out of interest, can WHERE MATCH do word boundaries? is it like LIKE?

Comment: `MATCH`, together with `FULLTEXT` does do word boundaries.  It is very different than `LIKE`, which has no concept of words unless you search for exactly what is before and after the 'word'.

Comment: @BenedictHarris - and `FULLTEXT` has limitations -- no "short" words, no words in the "stoplist" (which is aimed at common English words).

Comment: @BenedictHarris - Where does "mysqlx" come from??

Comment: so MATCH would be no good for country codes of two letters, such as DE? 
too short?

No idea where mysqlx is from. using My SQL 8.0.16

see screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/65zhQ.png

Comment: @BenedictHarris - Might there be country_codes in the text string?  You could set the "min_word_len = 2".

Answer (score 0):

You should make the regex into a trie.
This is less work for the engine, it only has to do at most 16 steps to fail
instead of the current  110 steps it's doing now.

Try

```
A(?:achen|ugsburg)|B(?:a(?:den-Württemberg|varia|yern)|er(?:gisch[ ]Gladbach|lin)|ielefeld|o(?:chum|nn|ttrop)|r(?:a(?:ndenbur|unschwei)g|eme(?:rhave)?n))|C(?:hemnitz|ologne)|D(?:armstadt|eutsch|ortmund|resden|uisburg|üsseldorf)|E(?:r(?:furt|langen)|ssen)|F(?:r(?:ankfurt|eiburg)|ürth)|G(?:e(?:lsenkirche|rma)n|öttingen)|H(?:a(?:gen|lle|m(?:burg|m)|n(?:n)?over)|e(?:i(?:delberg|lbronn)|rne|ssen?)|ildesheim)|Ingolstadt|Jena|K(?:a(?:rlsruhe|ssel)|iel|oblenz|refeld|öln)|L(?:e(?:ipzig|verkusen)|ower[ ]Saxony|udwigshafen|übeck)|M(?:a(?:gdeburg|inz|nnheim)|ecklenburg-Vorpommern|oers|unich|önchengladbach|ü(?:lheim|n(?:chen|ster)))|N(?:euss|iedersachsen|or(?:drhein-Westfalen|th[ ]Rhine-)|uremberg|ürnberg)|O(?:berhausen|ffenbach|ldenburg|snabrück)|P(?:aderborn|forzheim|otsdam)|R(?:e(?:cklinghausen|gensburg|mscheid|utlingen)|h(?:einland-Pfalz|ineland-Palatinate)|ostock)|S(?:a(?:a(?:le|r(?:brücken|land))|chsen(?:-Anhalt)?|lzgitter|xony(?:-Anhalt)?)|chleswig-Holstein|iegen|olingen|tuttgart)|T(?:h(?:uringia|üringen)|rier)|Ulm|W(?:estphalia|iesbaden|olfsburg|uppertal|ürzburg)
```

Change the `(?:` to `(` if your engine doesn't support non-capture syntax.
Also, you can change `[ ]` to just space if you want to on the compressed
regex.

https://regex101.com/r/iEzw33/1

Expanded

```
    A
    (?: achen | ugsburg )
 |  B
    (?:
         a
         (?: den-Württemberg | varia | yern )
      |  er
         (?: gisch [ ] Gladbach | lin )
      |  ielefeld
      |  o
         (?: chum | nn | ttrop )
      |  r
         (?:
              a
              (?: ndenbur | unschwei )
              g
           |  eme
              (?: rhave )?
              n
         )
    )
 |  C
    (?: hemnitz | ologne )
 |  D
    (?:
         armstadt
      |  eutsch
      |  ortmund
      |  resden
      |  uisburg
      |  üsseldorf
    )
 |  E
    (?:
         r
         (?: furt | langen )
      |  ssen
    )
 |  F
    (?:
         r
         (?: ankfurt | eiburg )
      |  ürth
    )
 |  G
    (?:
         e
         (?: lsenkirche | rma )
         n
      |  öttingen
    )
 |  H
    (?:
         a
         (?:
              gen
           |  lle
           |  m
              (?: burg | m )
           |  n
              (?: n )?
              over
         )
      |  e
         (?:
              i
              (?: delberg | lbronn )
           |  rne
           |  ssen?
         )
      |  ildesheim
    )
 |  Ingolstadt
 |  Jena
 |  K
    (?:
         a
         (?: rlsruhe | ssel )
      |  iel
      |  oblenz
      |  refeld
      |  öln
    )
 |  L
    (?:
         e
         (?: ipzig | verkusen )
      |  ower [ ] Saxony
      |  udwigshafen
      |  übeck
    )
 |  M
    (?:
         a
         (?: gdeburg | inz | nnheim )
      |  ecklenburg-Vorpommern
      |  oers
      |  unich
      |  önchengladbach
      |  ü
         (?:
              lheim
           |  n
              (?: chen | ster )
         )
    )
 |  N
    (?:
         euss
      |  iedersachsen
      |  or
         (?: drhein-Westfalen | th [ ] Rhine- )
      |  uremberg
      |  ürnberg
    )
 |  O
    (?:
         berhausen
      |  ffenbach
      |  ldenburg
      |  snabrück 
    )
 |  P
    (?: aderborn | forzheim | otsdam )
 |  R
    (?:
         e
         (?:
              cklinghausen
           |  gensburg
           |  mscheid
           |  utlingen 
         )
      |  h
         (?: einland-Pfalz | ineland-Palatinate )
      |  ostock
    )
 |  S
    (?:
         a
         (?:
              a
              (?:
                   le
                |  r
                   (?: brücken | land )
              )
           |  chsen
              (?: -Anhalt )?
           |  lzgitter
           |  xony
              (?: -Anhalt )?
         )
      |  chleswig-Holstein
      |  iegen
      |  olingen
      |  tuttgart
    )
 |  T
    (?:
         h
         (?: uringia | üringen )
      |  rier
    )
 |  Ulm
 |  W
    (?:
         estphalia
      |  iesbaden
      |  olfsburg
      |  uppertal
      |  ürzburg
    )
```

Lets check the speed:

```
Regex1:   A(?:achen|ugsburg)|B(?:a(?:den-Württemberg|varia|yern)|er(?:gisch[ ]Gladbach|lin)|ielefeld|o(?:chum|nn|ttrop)|r(?:a(?:ndenbur|unschwei)g|eme(?:rhave)?n))|C(?:hemnitz|ologne)|D(?:armstadt|eutsch|ortmund|resden|uisburg|üsseldorf)|E(?:r(?:furt|langen)|ssen)|F(?:r(?:ankfurt|eiburg)|ürth)|G(?:e(?:lsenkirche|rma)n|öttingen)|H(?:a(?:gen|lle|m(?:burg|m)|n(?:n)?over)|e(?:i(?:delberg|lbronn)|rne|ssen?)|ildesheim)|Ingolstadt|Jena|K(?:a(?:rlsruhe|ssel)|iel|oblenz|refeld|öln)|L(?:e(?:ipzig|verkusen)|ower[ ]Saxony|udwigshafen|übeck)|M(?:a(?:gdeburg|inz|nnheim)|ecklenburg-Vorpommern|oers|unich|önchengladbach|ü(?:lheim|n(?:chen|ster)))|N(?:euss|iedersachsen|or(?:drhein-Westfalen|th[ ]Rhine-)|uremberg|ürnberg)|O(?:berhausen|ffenbach|ldenburg|snabrück)|P(?:aderborn|forzheim|otsdam)|R(?:e(?:cklinghausen|gensburg|mscheid|utlingen)|h(?:einland-Pfalz|ineland-Palatinate)|ostock)|S(?:a(?:a(?:le|r(?:brücken|land))|chsen(?:-Anhalt)?|lzgitter|xony(?:-Anhalt)?)|chleswig-Holstein|iegen|olingen|tuttgart)|T(?:h(?:uringia|üringen)|rier)|Ulm|W(?:estphalia|iesbaden|olfsburg|uppertal|ürzburg)
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   110
Elapsed Time:    5.74 s,   5736.58 ms,   5736578 µs
Matches per sec:   958,759
```

Wow, a million words matched per second !

Comment: oh wow that worked. I also found an online tool to make a trie.

http://kemio.com.ar/tools/lst-trie-re.php

I am still wondering though - why don't I get a timeout on my local stack? I only get it on my AWS version.
what is the mysql setting to increase timeout limit?

Comment: another Q..does:
(?: as a non-capturing group save processor power or is it faster than "("  ?

Comment: The online trie tool is riddled with errors. It reminds be of where I was about 5 years ago when I designed mine [Tern Tool](http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg). Now its a mature tool with multiple uses, like creating [Emoji Regex](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn8/TernConv.jpg)  and stuff like a [175,000 Word Dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt). Recommend you use the tool in the link.

Comment: About the grouping performance. Capture groups require overhead to maintain them. [Mega-Bench 8](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg): `Regex1:   Using Non-Capturing group notation (?: )
Completed iterations:   30  /  30     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   110
Elapsed Time:    3.43 s,   3434.41 ms,   3434411 µs
Matches per sec:   960,863


Regex2:   Using Capturing group notation ( )
Completed iterations:   30  /  30     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   110
Elapsed Time:    10.33 s,   10333.74 ms,   10333744 µs
Matches per sec:   319,342`
.